# The stream or file var www storage logs laravel log could not be opened failed to open stream Permission denied

Tags: php, laravel, docker

I have two docker containers. I tried to change owners of storage and bootstrap/cache, but its not working.

Comment: Need more information , How you have change owner ? Share composer or docker file as well

Comment: I usually follow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30639174/how-to-set-up-file-permissions-for-laravel when I run into permissions issues for Laravel.

Comment: Please share more detail to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you're running the below commands INSIDE your Docker container and not from outside of the Docker container:

```bash
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:clear
```

This should fix your problem.  Running these commands outside of the Docker container (on your machine) will cause this problem to happen.